# Keep checkbox unchecked if saved

Tags: php, html

I have the following checkbox that I currently have checked by default

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Include In Top Sellers?</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="include_top" value="0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="include_top" id="include_top" value="1" 
                          <?php echo (($_POST["include_top"] == "1") or ($res["include_top"] == "1")) ? "checked='checked'" : ""; ?>
                            autocomplete="off" checked/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It's running inside a PHP file. Problem is, if I uncheck it and save it, I need it to stay unchecked. I still want the default to be checked. The php file is a template for new product settings in Magento. Not sure if a session or cookie would help here.

Comment: In `autocomplete="off" checked/>` you set it to *always* be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td align="right">Include In Top Sellers?</td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="include_top"
                            value="0"><input type="checkbox"
                            name="include_top"
                            id="include_top"
                            value="1" <?php echo (($_POST["include_top"] == "1") or ($res["include_top"] == "1") or (!array_key_exist('include_top', $_POST))) ? "checked='checked'" : ""; ?>
                            autocomplete="off"/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Why should anyone *try this*? What did you change from OPs original code, and why? A good answer always includes an explanation and a description.